# Tuition Reimbursement - No signed Clawback Policy

Tags: employment

I have worked for my current employer for 18 months and have been in grad school the entire time. I read the Employee Handbook the first day and honestly do not remember if or what was included in the tuition reimbursement section because I was using GI Bill benefits. As I neared the one year mark of employment a coworker mentioned tuition reimbursement, so I asked my department manager what I needed to do. He said I needed to apply and he would sign the request and pass to HR.

I completed the application: it asked what program I was attending, the class to be reimbursed for, and how the class/degree would benefit the department. This degree is specifically for being a program or department manager in my current field. There was a clause about passing the course with a B grade for reimbursement and needing to show proof of payment. The application did not have any statements about repayment. I was also unconcerned, as I did not intend to leave the job.

Fast forward a few months: my direct supervisor (manager) quit, and the position is vacant. I have been tasked with completing many managerial duties, even though I am still somewhat new. I have been asked to formally update nearly half of our programs and forms, completed reports, and written proposals and progress reports for the department. I told the administrative director I intended to apply for the manager position and asked if I was qualified. I was told to apply, and the director would talk to me and let me know if I was qualified. Spoiler alert: he still has not acknowledged that I applied for the position.

After a month with no response from the administrative director nor the department director I applied to other companies. I was immediately given an offer with another place for a significant pay increase--even more than what the manager position was paying. I submitted my resignation, I even gave 4 weeks notice as now they would be extremely short staffed and I care about my coworkers. The administrative director was in tears when I resigned, and asked if they could counteroffer, I said I would be open to a counteroffer. She said she'd talk to the director.

He came into my office a few hours later with my resignation in his hand and stood in the doorway and just glared at me without saying anything. I said he made me feel like a child who just disappointed their father. He just replied, "I understand you've been given an exceptional opportunity (the words I used in my resignation). I guess you have to take it." He then walked to my desk and showed a printout from the employee handbook, which stated there is a one-year commitment after receiving tuition assistance. "You have to pay this back now." Then he left my office.

I understand most places have a clawback policy with tuition assistance, and I was expecting to pay it back. However, the application I signed does not mention a clawback clause, nor did I sign any commitment length for receiving the assistance. Is the clawback policy still applicable even though I did not sign an understanding, nor was there any mention of having to repay the money if I quit?